# Read specific variables from a file and assign their values to those in my code

Tags: c, file

I'm not too practical with `c` or the "`c` way of doing stuff", and I stumbled upon a problem.
I have a file with some variables and their corresponding values such as

```
Var1 1
Var2 15
Var3 1.6
var4 SomeText
```

How can I read the variables from this file and assign it to variables with corresponding name in my code?
I'm looking for something in the style of

```c
double Var3 = ReadFromFile(File, "Var3");
```

so my main attempt was focused on trying to parse the "Var3" part from the file, but I can't manage to do it in `c`, so any help would be appreciated. I don't want to simply read the file in order since the placement of the variables in the file should be arbitrary so also

```
var4 SomeText
Var2 15
Var1 1
Var3 1.6
```

should be readable.
My code thus far is

```c
FILE* InstFile = fopen("Filename", "r");
char row[128];
while(fgets(row, sizeof(row), InstFile) != NULL) {
    //I don't know what to put here to select only the text I want and extract the value.
}
```

Comment: You could use [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the string at the first space, or use [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to find the first space. And use the first substring to compare against the key passed to the function.

Comment: And repeat this for each variable I need! That's actually a very good solution, thanks!

Comment: `assign it to variables with corresponding name in my code?` You can't, you can't generate variable names from input. Och maybe - do you know variable names before hand and they are limited in count? Or do you want to create a map string->value instead? As for `How can I read the variables from this file` - for simple cases, just `scanf`.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes I didn't formulate it very well, I know the names beforehand and want to fine the one I need in the file based on what I'm assigning in my code

Comment: If you don't expect the file to change during the run-time you could read and parse it at program startup, and store the key and value in an array or list. Then search through this array or list when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
int Var1 = ReadFromFile(File, "Var1");
int Var2 = ReadFromFile(File, "Var2");
double Var3 = ReadFromFile(File, "Var3");
char* Var4 = ReadFromFile(File, "Var4");
```

Well, **that's not possible**.

The reason is that a) A function can't return a `int` sometimes and a `double` other times and b) when you read from the file all values comes as text values so to get an `int` you need code to convert a text string to `int` and likewise for `double`.

In other words - it can't be done without **type information**.

Instead you can do:

```
int Var1 = ReadIntFromFile(File, "Var1");
int Var2 = ReadIntFromFile(File, "Var2");
double Var3 = ReadDoubleFromFile(File, "Var3");
char* Var4 = ReadTextFromFile(File, "Var3");
```

so that you have a specific function for each type.

Unless **the file is extremely big** this is what I would do:

At program start-up I would read the whole file into a (dynamic allocated) array of structs. Each struct would have two strings, i.e. a key-string to hold the variable name and another string to hold the value. Like:

```
struct key_value
{
    char key[32];
    char val[992];
};
```

So when `fgets` give a string like "Var2 15" the string must be split into two strings where the first string is copied to `key` and the second string to `val`. Something like:

```
char row[2000];
int i = 0;
while(fgets(row, sizeof(row), InstFile) != NULL) 
{
    if (sscanf(row, 
               "%31s %991s", 
               key_value_array[i].key, 
               key_value_array[i].val) != 2)
    {
        // Error - unexpected format
        exit(1);  // or something better...
    }
    ++i;
} 
 strcpy(key_value_array[i].key, "end_of_array");
 strcpy(key_value_array[i].val, "");
```

**note:** The code above doesn't check that size of `key_value_array` is sufficient to hold all the keys. Adding such a check I'll leave to OP.

I added an extra struct in the end to indicate end-of-array.

Now you can search the array of structs for the correct key and - if found - convert the value string in  accordance with the type information.

Something like:

```
int ReadInt(struct key_value * key_value_array, char * var_name)
{
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while( strcmp(key_value_array[i].key, "end_of_array") != 0 )
    {
        if( strcmp(key_value_array[i].key, var_name) == 0 )
        {
            // Variable found
            result = atoi(key_value_array[i].val);
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The good thing about this approach is that you only need to access the file once. Further the code for reading the file is completely independent of type information.

However, there is **one big problem here...** The code can't give you error information in case a specific variable name wasn't found or a type conversion failed.

So we need to add that.

This is what I would do:

```
int ReadInt(struct key_value * key_value_array, char * var_name, int* value)
{
    int i = 0;
    while( strcmp(key_value_array[i].key, "end_of_array") != 0 )
    {
        if( strcmp(key_value_array[i].key, var_name) == 0 )
        {
            // Variable found
            *value = atoi(key_value_array[i].val);
            return 0;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return -1; // Error, key not found
}
```

and call it like:

```
int Var1;
if (ReadInt(key_value_array, "Var1", &Var1)
{
    // Error handling... perhaps
    Var1 = some_default_value;
}
```

A last remark:

Global variables is something that should be avoided. However, configuration data like this is (IMO) an exception. Placing a file scope global array variable and all the associated function in one compilation unit would be fine. By doing that there would be no need to pass the array in all function calls. So a call could be:

```
int Var1;
if (ReadInt("Var1", &Var1)
{
    // Error handling... perhaps
    Var1 = some_default_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive step by step explanation! This is excellent!

Comment: @User.cpp See also last update for file reading

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that uses `strtok` and `strtod` to get a `double` based on a string you enter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WHITESPACE " \t\r\n"

double get_double_from_file(FILE *fp, const char *var_name)
{
    rewind(fp);
    for (char *vname, buf[1024]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp);)
    {
        if (strcmp((vname = strtok(buf, WHITESPACE)), var_name) == 0)
        {
            char *vstr = strtok(NULL, WHITESPACE);
            char *errptr;
            double dv = strtod(vstr, &errptr);
            if (*errptr != '\0')
            {
                // handle error
            }
            return dv;
        }
    }
    // handle if string not found
    return 0.0;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("foo.txt", "r");
    printf("%lf\n", get_double_from_file(fp, "Var2"));
}
```

So if my `foo.txt` is:

```
Var1 1.23
Var2 4.56
Var3 7.89
```

Output is:

```
4.560000
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest simplest design is just `sscanf` and check one at a time:

```
int var1;
float var2;
// etc...
while(fgets(...) != NULL) {
    if (sscanf(line, "Var1 %d", &var1) == 1) {
         // yay - var1 assigned
    } else if (sscanf(line, "Var2 %f", &var2) == 1) {
          // yay - var2 assigned
    } else {
         // invalid input - display error
         continue;
    }
}
```

You can extract first word first with `strtok` and then `sscanf` the value or scan the value with `strtoi/strtof/other`.

```
int var1;
float var2;
// etc...
while(fgets(...) != NULL) {
    const char delim[] = " ";
    char *firstword = strtok(line, delim);
    char *value = strtok(NULL, delim);
    if (firstword == NULL) {
        // error - nothing on the line
        continue;
    }
    if (value == NULL) {
        // error - only one thing on the line
        continue;
    }
    if (strcmp(firstword, "Var1") == 0) {
        if (sscanf(value, "%d", &var1) == 1) {
            // error
           continue;
        }
        // use var1
    } else if (strcmp(firstword, "Var2") == 0) {
        if (sscanf(value, "%f", &var2) == 1) {
            // error
             continue;
        }
        // use var2
    } else {
        // error - invalid first word
        continue;
    }
}
```

ie. sky the limit. You should definitely research how to deal with strings in C and all string-related functions and research about `sscanf` manual - `scanf` can be tricky to get it safe and right.

Comment: This is actually really complete and versatile

Comment: A solution for this shouldn't use specific variable names in the file reading code

Comment: @4386427 As I understood , there is a limited, before-hand known count and types of variables, ideally I pictured it's a structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of the function `ReadDoubleFromFile`.

My version of the function has the following advantages:

1. It returns whether it was able to find the name in the file or not.
2. It performs extensive input validation.
3. It does not use `strtok`, so it is thread-safe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//The following function will return true if it was able to
//find the name in the file, false otherwise. If it returns
//true, the found value will be written to *pd.
bool ReadDoubleFromFile( FILE *fp, const char *name, double *pd )
{
    char line[200];
    size_t name_len = strlen(name);

    //rewind file position to start
    rewind( fp );

    //read one line per loop iteration
    while( fgets( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL)
    {
        //count and remember length of line
        size_t line_len = strlen(line);

        //remove newline character, if it exists
        if ( line_len > 0 && line[line_len-1] == '\n' )
            line[--line_len] = '\0';

        //check line length
        if ( line_len == sizeof line - 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "error: line too long\n" );
            return false;
        }

        //check if all characters of name match
        if ( strncmp( name, line, name_len ) != 0 )
            continue;

        //check if there are additional characters (which would
        //mean that there is no match)
        if ( line[name_len] != ' ' )
            continue;

        //attempt to convert the rest of the line to double
        char *end;
        *pd = strtod( line + name_len + 1 , &end );

        //check if the entire rest of the line was converted
        if ( *end != '\0' )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "error: conversion to double failed\n" );
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```